# How the processor itself assumes the execution time of any program?

Tags: c, linux, scheduling

Suppose I have written some c programs.And the OS has **SJF(shortest job first)** scheduling policy so how will CPU decide the **execution time** for all the processes before actually executing them.Ex. every time whichever the short process that will be executed first in SJF.

Comment: The CPU is running code. Either kernel code or user code. Time is measured by some code somewhere, using available hardware timers and other devices

Comment: Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.makelinux.net/alp) since you are *very* confused, and wikipages on *operating system*, *linux*, *kernel*, *system call*, *microprocessor*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented below, apparently Linux does not have a job control scripting language, so you should probably remove that tag, as well as the C tag.

On systems with job scheduling, there's some type of job control scripting language where the estimated run time is included in the information needed to run the job.

Example Wiki articles:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_Control_Language

In this case, the estimated time is specified as a job parameter:

```
/*JOBPARM TIME=10
```

for a time estimate of 10 minutes. On this web page, scroll down to the TIME parameter description:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.ieab600/iea3b6_Parameter_definition5.htm

Based on the description, if the time is exceeded, the operator is notified. I'm not sure what happens on unattended systems.

Comment: Can you please elaborate sir, how is this JCL internally doing this job.?How its calculating the estimated time.?

Comment: In the case of mainframes, it's up to the user to specify an estimated time in the JCL, based on having run the job before, or based on running similar jobs, or an estimate of the time. If the time was exceeded, a smart OS could suspend the job, lower it's priority, then run it later. Since the 1970's, mainframes can run multiple jobs at the same time, so the job scheduling is more complicated, than the classroom examples. These days, a high end operating system can run multiple operating systems at the same time, like [ibm z/os](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z/OS) .

Comment: Continuing, In the old days, the JCL could also inform the operator to hook up specific external storage, such as tapes, removable disk packs, or perhaps to put pre-printed forms into line printer. I don't know if any of this legacy stuff is done anymore.

Comment: Thanks sir, JCL is the totally new concept i got from you today, but after some exploration I have assumed that CPU decides the time on basis of assembly code of the program by calculating the machine cycles per instructions, Is it relevant?

Comment: JCL does not apply to Linux, which has `batch`, `at`, shells, `crontab` etc